# Good naming conventions for accessibilityIdentifier? - XCode 7 UI Test - Recording

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

Are there established naming conventions for accessibility identifiers (in relation to Xcode UI Test recording)?

I'm looking into accessibility and UI tests. I played with the new Record functionality in Xcode 7. While recording UI actions, I noticed:

When I have a button labeled "a" and record a tap twice, I get this code:

```
XCUIElement *aButton = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init].buttons[@"a"];
[aButton tap];
[aButton tap];
```

When I set its accessibilityIdentifier to "a" and repeat the recording, I get the same code.

Can localized labels interfere with accessibility identifiers? (If in some language button X suddenly has "a" as the label and button Y has "a" as the accessibility identifier - will this be ambiguous / conflicting?)

My first thought was to have a unique prefix for accessibility identifiers - say "@". So I tried "@a", "@1", etc.

However, with "@1" the recording leads to this code:

```
XCUIElement *1Button = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init].buttons[@"@1"];
[1Button tap];
[1Button tap];
```

This produces compiler errors, as `1Button` is not a valid identifier. Obviously the accessibility identifier is prepended to the button's variable name with some characters stripped.

With "1" the recording leads to this code:

```
XCUIElement *button = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init].buttons[@"1"];
[button tap];
[button tap];
```

Which leads to another question:

Can I influence how Xcode derives the names of the variables during recording?

I know, that I can just do the recording and clean up variable names manually. However, that would be silly, if it could be easily configured somewhere.

Comment: You can answer the first question by testing this case, can't you ? Would probably take even less time than writing this part of the question. As for your second question, I like to think about such tools from its developers perspective and in this case can't see why they would implement something like that.

Comment: @A-Live Well, the developers caught the cases where the ids are numbers. They strip special characters, so the variables won't be named `@button`. As a developer myself, I'd went the little step further to take care of ids like `@1` too. It looks like it would be as easy as applying the number check after the special character stripping instead of before. (Big tools like Xcode are never easy, so this might not be as easy as it seems.) Considering that Apple recommends to walk the extra mile for the user, I'd expect that here too. So I wonder whether some gurus know more about it than I do :-)

Comment: The last time I asked Apple about it using Apple devs tech support they had to recommend to use http://bugreport.apple.com and submit an "Enhancement" problem there, you might want to do that.